# Place a button inside DialogFragment's title

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I show a `DialogFragment` from another `DialogFragment`. I need to set title and a button just next to it. I don't want to reimplement the theme and create a custom view inside `DialogFragment`'s content view instead of dialog title (because it's error-prone and time wasting). Is it even possible? I tried many API functions, `AlertBuilder`, `ActionBar`, this and that, still didn't found anything that fits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Title
final int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle","id","android");
TextView title = (TextView) popup.findViewById(titleId);
title.setText("My new title");

// Title's parent layout
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) title.getRootView();

// Button
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("A Button");
viewGroup.addView(button);
```

*Note:* You may need to adjust the `button` and `title` objects' `LayoutParams`.

Comment: That worked. Small fix: I used `TextView title = (TextView) getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title)`

Comment: @efpies you may want to be careful using `android.R.id.title` as well as `alertTitle`. I remember trying both and only the latter worked. Perhaps it's device dependent. So you may want to add a null check :)

Answer (score 1):

An update. This can be achieved by calling `setCustomTitle` on `AlertDialog.Builder` class. Available since api level 1, and do not require a bunch of code.

Example:

`AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setCustomTitle(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, viewGroup)).create()`