# Set Done Button on Kotlin DialogFragment with multi choice Items

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, fragment

I have a DialogFragment with multi chose style, which means it does not dismiss on select/deselect. The only way to dismiss it seems to be to click on the device Back button.

Im finding it strange to have click the device back button to dismiss the dialog. **Is there a way to add a `Done` button to the dialog**, next to the title?

[image]

Comment: are you using AlertDialog or What ?

Comment: @MohammedAlaa yes I am sir.

Comment: I'm currently trying this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530127/place-a-button-inside-dialogfragments-title

Comment: there is an answer that state that you should adjust the layout-prams for button, also you can try other solutions like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932832/multiple-choice-alertdialog-with-custom-adapter?lq=1), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855974/how-to-make-an-alertdialog-with-multichoice-items-along-with-an-edittext)

Comment: @MohammedAlaa those links just show how to creare multiple chose dialog. My question is on adding a button next to the dialogs main title (at the top). As here: stackoverflow.com/questions/25530127/…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple actually, I'm extending the [theoretical answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33220763/870565):

Create your custom layout eg as myLayoutTitle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/select_type_title_container"
    android:background="#f6f6f6">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/select_type_title_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/select_type_title_container"
        android:text="@string/menu_types"
        android:layout_gravity ="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/select_types_textview"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/select_type_title_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/select_type_title_container"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/done_select_types"
        android:layout_gravity ="center_vertical"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The on your dialog builder

```
builder.setCustomTitle(activity?.layoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.myLayoutTitle, null))
```